# Google Search Console and Testing Tool giving different errors about best/worst AggregateRating values

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

On Google Search Console, I'm getting the error [missing best and worst rating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izN3j.png). But when I tested the link on testing tool, [I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlJVy.png):

1. > Failed to normalize the rating value.
2. > Your rating value was out of the default range, you must provide best and worst values.

The code is given below:

```html
<h3>Reviews</h3>
<div class="average-rating" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
<p class="rating-title">Average Rating</p>
<div class="rating-box">
    <div class="average-value" itemprop="ratingValue">0/5</div>
    <div class="review-amount" itemprop="ratingCount">0 rating</div>
</div>
```

When I change in rating value to

```html
<div class="average-value" itemprop="ratingValue">0/5</div>
```

or to this

```html
<div class="average-value" itemprop="ratingValue">0/-454545</div>
```

it [gives a warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeKer.png):

> 0 rating (The value provided for `ratingCount` must be an integer.)

How can I solve this?

Comment: though I tried to do it by providing `<div class="average-value" itemprop="ratingValue" min="0" max="5"> rating 0</div>` it only gave a warning mentioned above

Comment: Both errors say that you miss specifying the best/worst rating, and your markup doesn’t provide either. Do you know how to add properties for best/worst rating?

Comment: here min and max provide the best and worst rating :      `<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">
 <p itemprop="name">PRODUCT_NAME</p>
   <div class="average-rating" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
      <p class="rating-title">Average Rating</p>
      <div class="rating-box">
          <div class="average-value"
              itemprop="ratingValue" min="0" max ="5">0/5</div>
          <div class="review-amount" itemprop="ratingCount">0 ratings</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`min`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-min)/[`max`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-max) attributes are plain HTML attributes, they don’t affect the Microdata (and they can, by the way, not be used on `div` elements).

In Schema.org, the worst/best rating can be specified with [`worstRating`](http://schema.org/worstRating) and [`bestRating`](http://schema.org/bestRating). If you don’t provide these properties, "0" and "5" are assumed.

If you fix the other errors (`ratingCount` would have to be "0", not "0 rating"; and it might be better to use "0" instead of "0/5" as `ratingValue`), you could omit `worstRating`/`bestRating`. But it’s typically better to be explicit, so you could add:

```html
<meta itemprop="worstRating" content="0" />
<meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
```

or:

```html
<meta itemprop="worstRating" content="0" />
<span itemprop="ratingValue">0</span>/<span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>
```